# Django: ajax not returning or sending any data in django

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

i am creating a simple like button with ajax, i have followed the tutorial but it seems, that i am missing something, i am not getting any error either in the console in my django terminal but when i click the button no data get sent, evrything just remains the same way, and this is not what i am expecting, i know i am missing something somewhere and i cannot really tell where this error is coming from.

views.py

```
@login_required
def like(request):
    if request.POST.get("action") == 'post':
        result = ""
        id = int(request.POST.get('courseid'))
        course = get_object_or_404(Course, id=id)

        if course.like.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            course.like.remove(request.user)
            course.like_count -= 1
            result = course.like_count
            course.save()
        else:
            course.like.add(request.user)
            course.like_count += 1
            result = course.like_count
            course.save()
        return JsonResponse({'result': result})
```

urls.py NOTE:**I don't know if i need a slug in this url path**

```
    path('like/', views.like, name="like"),
```

base.html

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

course-detail.html

```
<li><button id="like-button" value="{{course.id}}">like</button><span id="like-count">{{course.llke_count}}</span></li>



<script type="text/javascript">
        
    $(document).on("click", '#like-button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url 'course:like' course.slug %}',
            data: {
                courseid: $('#like-button').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
                action: 'post'
            },
            success: function(json){
                document.getElementById("like-count").innerHTML = json['result']
                console.log(json)
            },
            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err)
            console.log(xhr)
            console.log(errmsg)
            console.log(err)
        })
    })

</script>
```

this is all the code i have written for the functionality, if there is any other thing to be provided i will update the question

**UPDATE AFTER FIRST ANSWER**
**#####################################################################**

Now when i click the like button is does show an visible error but the like count now shows `undefined` and in my chrome dev tools is shows `failed to load response data because this request was redirected`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code like this and I've doubt about your like table provide that inside your question.

inside your **views.py**

```
@login_required
def like(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = ""
        course_id = int(request.POST.get('courseid'))
        course = get_object_or_404(Course, id=course_id)

        if course.like.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            course.like.remove(request.user)
            course.like_count -= 1
            result = course.like_count
            course.save()
        else:
            course.like.add(request.user)
            course.like_count += 1
            result = course.like_count
            course.save()
        return JsonResponse({'result': result})
```

inside your **course-detail.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#like-button").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{% url 'course:like' %}",
            data: {
                courseid: $('#like-button').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
            },
            success: function (json) {
                document.getElementById("like-count").innerHTML = json['result']
                console.log(json)
            },
            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
                console.log(xhr)
                console.log(errmsg)
                console.log(err)
            }

        })
    })

</script>
```

**Note :**

1. You don't have to check for action instead you can check for method eg. **`request.method`**.
2. You've provided wrong url inside your ajax call **`'{% url 'course:like' course.slug %}'`** it should be **`'{% url 'course:like' %}'`** without passing slug.
3. Do not use id as avariable because it will conflict with python [**`id()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function, you can check for all available built-in functions in python [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Comment: txks for your response, i learnt alot - but now it shows this error in the chrome dev tool and when i click on the like button is now shows undefined `failed to load response data because this request was redirected` i have attached an image

Comment: Hello @DestinyFranks provide your browser console and your cmd output inside your question. It seems your user is not authenticated and it's getting redirected for that.